# FPGA and SDRAM noise impact on ADC input

Tags: adc, fpga, clock, sdram

I'm using an FPGA to get data from an ADC and save them on SDRAM, the SDRAM works with 100 MHz and the ADC works with a 40 MHz clock so I use a clock IPCORE to generate them from my 50 MHz oscillator but the problem is SDRAM is affecting ADC's clock and I'm getting a patterned signal.

My PCB schematic shown in fig.1.

[image: FIG.1]

when I use a separate oscillator on the input with separate ip cores for generating a clock for the SDRAM and ADC the pattern is reduced.

[image: FIG.2]

The question is what is the problem and how can I use a single oscillator for generating a good clock signal for both of them?

Here are the parameters I used for Xilinx clock IPCORE:

```
(* CORE_GENERATION_INFO = "Clock,clk_wiz_v3_6,{component_name=Clock,use_phase_alignment=true,use_min_o_jitter=false,use_max_i_jitter=false,use_dyn_phase_shift=false,use_inclk_switchover=false,use_dyn_reconfig=false,feedback_source=FDBK_AUTO,primtype_sel=DCM_SP,num_out_clk=2,clkin1_period=20.0,clkin2_period=20.0,use_power_down=false,use_reset=false,use_locked=false,use_inclk_stopped=false,use_status=false,use_freeze=false,use_clk_valid=false,feedback_type=SINGLE,clock_mgr_type=AUTO,manual_override=false}" *)
module Clock
 (// Clock in ports
  input         CLK_IN,
  // Clock out ports
  output        CLK_DATA,
  output        CLK_RAM
 );

  // Input buffering
  //------------------------------------
  IBUFG clkin1_buf
   (.O (clkin1),
    .I (CLK_IN));


  // Clocking primitive
  //------------------------------------

  // Instantiation of the DCM primitive
  //    * Unused inputs are tied off
  //    * Unused outputs are labeled unused
  wire        psdone_unused;
  wire        locked_int;
  wire [7:0]  status_int;
  wire clkfb;
  wire clk0;
  wire clk2x;
  wire clkfx;

  DCM_SP
  #(.CLKDV_DIVIDE          (2.000),
    .CLKFX_DIVIDE          (5),
    .CLKFX_MULTIPLY        (4),
    .CLKIN_DIVIDE_BY_2     ("FALSE"),
    .CLKIN_PERIOD          (20.0),
    .CLKOUT_PHASE_SHIFT    ("NONE"),
    .CLK_FEEDBACK          ("2X"),
    .DESKEW_ADJUST         ("SYSTEM_SYNCHRONOUS"),
    .PHASE_SHIFT           (0),
    .STARTUP_WAIT          ("FALSE"))
  dcm_sp_inst
    // Input clock
   (.CLKIN                 (clkin1),
    .CLKFB                 (clkfb),
    // Output clocks
    .CLK0                  (clk0),
    .CLK90                 (),
    .CLK180                (),
    .CLK270                (),
    .CLK2X                 (clk2x),
    .CLK2X180              (),
    .CLKFX                 (clkfx),
    .CLKFX180              (),
    .CLKDV                 (),
    // Ports for dynamic phase shift
    .PSCLK                 (1'b0),
    .PSEN                  (1'b0),
    .PSINCDEC              (1'b0),
    .PSDONE                (),
    // Other control and status signals
    .LOCKED                (locked_int),
    .STATUS                (status_int),
    .RST                   (1'b0),
    // Unused pin- tie low
    .DSSEN                 (1'b0));


  // Output buffering
  //-----------------------------------
  BUFG clkf_buf
   (.O (clkfb),
    .I (clk2x));

  BUFG clkout1_buf
   (.O   (CLK_DATA),
    .I   (clkfx));


  BUFG clkout2_buf
   (.O   (CLK_RAM),
    .I   (clk2x));



endmodule
```

Comment: How are you generating the clock for the ADC? Most likely an issue of clock jitter

Comment: @TomCarpenter Im generating the clock for the ADC with an IPCORE that generates a 100 MHz clock for SDRAM and a 40 MHz for ADC. Is there any way to generate a low-jitter clock from FPGA?

Comment: "an IPCORE" is not really enough to go on. Custom one (if so post code) or commercial one (if so link to datasheet and specify parameters used). FPGAs are not great at making low jitter clocks - most mixed signal systems will use an external clock generator IC.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Im using Xilinx clocking wizard IPCORE. I updated my post with the parameters.

Comment: @Md.shah Did you put time-/jitter-constraints on the clock lines? Otherwise the tool will maybe route them through the entire fabric...And that will produce a lot of phase jitter and also EMI. Both not good for the ADC. Also: PLLs generally tend to have a lot of phase jitter. It would be adviseable to use the raw XTAL Clk (50MHz, or change to XTAL to 40MHz) for the ADC and use a x2 multiple for the RAM. (x2 multiples are always good, as the harmonics are "in phase"...somewhat) You could also use a FIR Anti-Aliasing Filter - which is in any case adviseable and will help with your problems.

Comment: As Tom said, it probably is much better to have an external high-quality 40 MHz xtal/clock IC, use it for the ADC directly and route the clock to FPGA.